# Panel in StatusStrip?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, statusstrip

Is it possible to have a panel in a `StatusStrip`? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.statusstrip.aspx) is kind of saying so:

> The default StatusStrip has no panels. To add panels to a StatusStrip, use the [ToolStripItemCollection.AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitemcollection.addrange.aspx) method [...]

... but I can't find how.

I tried to add a `Panel` or a `ToolStripPanel` to a `StatusStrip`, but it is only accepting `ToolStripItem`s. On the other hand, I tried adding a `ToolStripItem` to a `Panel` or a `ToolStripPanel`, but both only accepts `Control`s:

```
ToolStripPanel toolStripPanel = new ToolStripPanel();
toolStripPanel.Controls.Add(toolStripStatusLabel);   // Wrong
statusStrip.Items.AddRange(toolStripPanel);          // Wrong again
```

Comment: Yes, won't work, wrong flavors.  It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish, good odds that you are looking for the ToolStripControlHost class.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm trying to group several ToolStripItems into a panel in order to do hide/show that panel (I can't hide/show each items for some good reasons). I don't think ToolStripControlHost provides the functionality to contain ToolStripItems, does it?

Comment: No, but you can put a ToolStrip or ToolStripPanel inside of it.  Which in turn can host ToolStripItems.

Answer (score 1):

What's interesting is that in Microsoft terms

> ToolStripStatusLabel - Represents a panel in a StatusStrip control.

So their panel is really a Label. Unless that's a mistake in their documentation, what you are trying to do is impossible, as there is no Panel class that can be hosted inside StatusStrip.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ToolStripStatusLabel. In order to have the look and feel of a Panel, simply set the following properties of the ToolStripStatusLabel:
**BorderSides** = All,
**BorderStyle** = SunkenOuter